# JPQL Query with join and where clause subquery

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I am new to JPQL and am trying to write a join query that gets results from a subquery in the where clause. What I have lloks like this:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT distinct pt.srcCanum FROM Pmt pt " + 
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN pt.txnhistPK ps " +                     
            "WHERE  " +
            "pt.isudDt > '2015-08-01' and pt.certdDt is null " + 
            "OR ps.pmtUid = "+
            "ALL(SELECT pq.pmtUid FROM txnhistPK pq" +
            "WHERE pq.pmtChngTs  > '2015-08-01')");
```

But it doesn't work. I have tried many different ways and none work. Please help.

Stack trace:
javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "ps . pmtUid exists" at character 131, but expected: ["(", "*", "+", "-", ".", "/", ":", "<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">", ">=", "?", "ABS", "ALL", "AND", "ANY", "AS", "ASC", "AVG", "BETWEEN", "BOTH", "BY", "CONCAT", "COUNT", "CURRENT_DATE", "CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DELETE", "DESC", "DISTINCT", "EMPTY", "ESCAPE", "EXISTS", "FETCH", "FROM", "GROUP", "HAVING", "IN", "INNER", "IS", "JOIN", "LEADING", "LEFT", "LENGTH", "LIKE", "LOCATE", "LOWER", "MAX", "MEMBER", "MIN", "MOD", "NEW", "NOT", "NULL", "OBJECT", "OF", "OR", "ORDER", "OUTER", "SELECT", "SET", "SIZE", "SOME", "SQRT", "SUBSTRING", "SUM", "TRAILING", "TRIM", "TYPE", "UPDATE", "UPPER", "WHERE", , , , , , , , ]." while parsing JPQL "SELECT distinct pt.srcCanum FROM Pmt pt LEFT OUTER JOIN pt.txnhistPK ps WHERE pt.isudDt > '2015-08-01' and pt.certdDt is null OR ps.pmtUid exists ALL(SELECT pq.pmtUid FROM txnhistPK pqWHERE pq.pmtChngTs > '2015-08-01')". See nested stack trace for original parse error.

character 131 is the p in ps after the OR. The entities should not need to be posted to understand. First, they are huge. Here is a short rundown: pmt has a pmtUid and srcCanum. txnhist holds changes to pmt's and contains a composite key (txnhistPK) that contains pmtUid and pmtChngTs. I need the results from both tables when the criterion in the query are met.

Comment: If you are getting an exception, then add the stack-trace. Or else if the query does not return the expected result without throwing an exception, add the relevant details too - what it returns and what is expected it to return. In any case, observe the generated SQL statement for a possible clue.

Comment: nobody can help unless you post the entities that that JPQL refers to. And what is character 131 of the query???

Comment: character 131 is the p in ps after the OR. The entities should not need to be posted to understand. First, they are huge. Here is a short rundown: pmt has a pmtUid and srcCanum. txnhist holds changes to pmt's and contains a composite key (txnhistPK) that contains pmtUid and pmtChngTs. I need the results from both tables when the criterion in the query are met.

Comment: if using AND and OR then put brackets around clauses to clarify the precedence. Details about entities should go in your QUESTION, not in the comments

Comment: I tried parentheses, not brackets. Didn't work.

Comment: "parentheses" are "brackets". Your subquery cannot use "txnhistPK" (some composite key apparently) as a the candidate entity! Your JPA implementation is which one?

Comment: {}s are brackets ()s are parentheses. It is JPA 2.0. Why can't I use txnhistPK in the subquery? Should I use txnhist.id.pmtChngTs?

Comment: "{" is a curly bracket, and "(" is a bracket, but whatever you want to call it, the JPA spec tells you what you can use. Any candidate of a query or subquery has to be an ENTITY.

Comment: Try this:  SELECT distinct pt.srcCanum FROM Pmt pt LEFT OUTER JOIN pt.txnhistPK ps WHERE (pt.isudDt > '2015-08-01' and pt.certdDt is null) OR ps.pmtUid = ALL(SELECT pq.pmtUid FROM txnhistPK pq WHERE pq.pmtChngTs > '2015-08-01')